# UIViewController class with IBOutlet collection still has connections to no longer existing storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, swift4, iboutletcollection

So, I have a class that still has connections to a deleted Drawers.storyboard file.

How do I 'clean' or remove the old connections to the non existing storyboard?

[image]

Comment: You deleted the view? But still has the connections in the "class"?

Comment: Yes, The Drawers.storyboard file has been deleted

Comment: And you're getting an error while running the application, right?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7ff911da3900> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key buttons.

Comment: buttons is one of the outlet collections

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it.
It looks like it was a cache issue....

I did this in the terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

Comment: Perfect, you fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to solve this:

```
1.) Rightclick on your project. 
2.) Show in Finder
3.) Find the "Drawers.storyboard"
4.) Drag it into your project again.
5.) Enter the storyboard and right click on the view.
6.) Remove all connections.
```

If I'm wrong, please tell me and I'll edit my answer.